# Downloading content of all files held within a parent folder on IPFS

Tags: http, web-scraping, ipfs

Say an IPFS folder contains (or rather, "points" to) several files. I wish to download the content within all of those files in one process, instead of making an individual HTTP request for each file within the folder. Traditionally, you would simply download the parent folder/directory, and in doing so, you would download the content of all files held within that folder/directory. Is it possible to do this with an IPFS folder? If so, how?

Comment: I have the same problem.
IPFS is not very common on the end machines.
It is not even part of the standard packages in most distros.
It is possible to get a "directory" from IPFS HTTP Endpoint if you upload a  "tar" or "tar.gz", but if you do so, you loose the benefit of deduplication  - what was the initial reason for me to use IPFS. I Suppose that it is currently not possible, but i am not sure.